# Gear shift wire on SRAM after an accident

Tags: gears

Took a pretty good fall after narrowly avoiding being hit by a speeding driver in the middle of a two lane road.

Managed to get the chain assembly back together but can’t figure out where this wire goes. Please see the following picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqSY4.jpg

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular derailer, but the cable end should probably be retained under the kind of washer with fingers around the bolt in the middle of the picture.  Probably the cable wraps around the end of that black "finger" sticking up in the picture (down when the bike is right side up) and then connects to the washer/bolt.  It can be tricky to get the wire properly positioned under the washer, and (I can't tell from the picture) it may be that the bolt is messed up a bit from your spill.

Comment: The orientation of the picture isn't ideal, but DRH's answer seems reasonable; See this video when they install the cable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTOyxOPHoGc

Comment: `"pretty good fall"` is that like 'plane landings? A good landing is one you walk away from, a great landing is when the plane flies next day.

Comment: Another consideration is whether to use the old cable or to install a new one. It might be worth having a new one, looking at the condition of that one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

It should run something like this, and be pinched under the washer behind the pinch bolt. judging by the scratches on your derailleur (if they are from the fall), it's pretty likely that your derailleur and/or derailleur hanger are bent.

SRAM has pretty great manuals @ service.sram.com if you know the model of your derailleur that should include cable routing.

Comment: Since the shifter cable has become untwisted at the end I would recommend that you replace the cable to avoid injury. Or have it replaced by a bike mechanic who could also inspect the derailleur for damage like @Paul hints.

Comment: Yep, you're right on the money. The derailer hanger is definitely bent.